# Application suddenly can't connect to my database server

Tags: c#, mysql

So I just encountered a problem when I tried to put my connection string in my app.config file. After this I got the following MySQL error:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException was unhandled
ErrorCode=-2147467259
HResult=-2147467259
Message=Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Number=1042
Source=MySql.Data
StackTrace:
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at SalesKicker2.Connector.connectionOpen(Boolean open) in F:\C# Projects\SalesKicker2\SalesKicker2\Connector.cs:line 38
   at SalesKicker2.gebruikerGegevens.btnNext_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in F:\C# Projects\SalesKicker2\SalesKicker2\gebruikerGegevens.xaml.cs:line 38
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at SalesKicker2.App.Main() in F:\C# Projects\SalesKicker2\SalesKicker2\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

I find this very wierd since the following line I'm using worked before:

```
"Server=myremoteserverip; Port=3306; Database=mydb; Uid=myusername; Pwd=mypass"
```

This worked perfectly before on my VPS. This server is obviously not hosted localy. I looked up many articles and still haven't found any good solution. The reason why I'm using my connection string in my app.config file is that you can't find it with a decompiler. This is how I put my connection string in my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
</startup>
<appSettings>
  <add key="connection" value="Server=ip; Port=3306; Database=db; Uid=usr; Pwd=pass"/>
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I'm using a key because the connectionString only tries to connect to a local database. Which shouldn't really happen obviously. This is how I use the connection string in my C# code:

```
public static string conString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connection"];
public static MySqlConnection SalesKicker = new MySqlConnection(conString);
```

as you can see the error is telling me about a bool. this bool triggers the SalesKicker.open() event like this:

```
    public static void connectionOpen(bool open)
    {
        if (open)
            SalesKicker.Open();
        if (!open)
            SalesKicker.Close();
    }
```

the exception is thrown at SalesKicker.Open();. I'm really confused and don't really know what I'm doing wrong here. Can someone please point me out my mistakes. I really want to know how to do this correctly

NOTE:

My MySQL server is indeed up and running

Comment: Can you connect with CLI to that server from the machine running your code?

Comment: I don't have one, can this be done through SSH? or do I need a specific CLI client?

Comment: CLI stands for command line interface. You just need the mysql client installed on your machine. If you prefer gui applications have a look at MySQL Workbench

Comment: I can not connect. It says that I have to check if the mysql server is running. My VPS has PLESK this is where I can access my phpmyadmin for the database. the database says localhost but it has always been like this. So I still find it wierd.

Comment: I've never used PLESK but you probably have to bind mysql to your public ip in your my.cnf (or use PLESK if it has any option to do so)

Comment: So sorry for the late answer, where do I find this my.cnf file?

Comment: Hi, give a look at this: https://kb.plesk.com/en/1134 . Or you can try 'find / -name my.cnf'. Remember opening up mysql port to the internet it'll make the database vulnerable to attack